# HttpRuntime Close does not remove items from the Cache as advertised

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-2.0

I've created my own cache manager for a web site I'm developing and I was looking to find the best way to clear the cache under certain circumstances.

I found many articles saying the proper way to clear the cache is to call HttpRuntime.Close()

However, in my unit tests setup I call the encapsulated function HttpRuntime.Close() and the cache is NOT being cleared out.

I expected it to perform something similar to

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry cacheItem in HttpRuntime.Cache)
{
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(cacheItem.Key.ToString());
}
```

The foreach loop works great in my encapsulated function, but the Close() never works right.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of HttpRuntime.Close() or is there something more sinister going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use Close, it does more than the docs say. And the docs also say not to use it while processing normal requests...

This is the reflected source of Close():

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted=true)]
public static void Close() {
    if (_theRuntime.InitiateShutdownOnce()) {
        SetShutdownReason(ApplicationShutdownReason.HttpRuntimeClose, "HttpRuntime.Close is called");
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted) {
            HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdown();
        } else {
            _theRuntime.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you cannot iterate over a collection and remove items from it at the same time, as this renders the enumeration invalid.

So, try this instead, which doesn't change what it loops over:

```
List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();
foreach (DictionaryEntry cacheItem in HttpRuntime.Cache) {
    toRemove.Add(cacheItem.Key.ToString());
}
foreach (string key in toRemove) {
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key);
}
```

That being said, really, you should try to use cache dependencies to have the invalid cache entries cleared automatically for you, and then all this becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Actually I've already tested the code I put in my question and it works fine.  I understand the issue with enumeration but for some reason the Cache doesn't seem to have a problem removing an item while walking through the list.

Comment: That's not really my question though.  What I'm saying is, if I have 4 items in the Cache, and I loop through it the way I've described, the Cache ends up with 0 items.  However, when I use Close(), the 4 items are still there.

Comment: That's because the docs state something which is not the full truth. Close() is not meant to be used to clear the cache.

Comment: Ouch, ok thanks for the heads up on that.  What do you mean by cache dependencies?

Comment: When entries are added to the cache, you can give them dependencies like timeout, a file, another cached entry etc., which will clear out the cache item if this dependency triggers. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> > I understand the issue with enumeration but for some reason the Cache doesn't seem to have a problem removing an item while walking through the list.

If you drill down to the detail implementation, you will find the Enumerator is created by CacheSingle.CreateEnumerator, a new Hashtable instance is created for enumeration.

That's why you can do the remove in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply implement your own Cache class, check the below one:

```
 public sealed class YourCache<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string, T> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    private YourCache()
    {
    }

    public static YourCache<T> Current
    {
        get
        {
            string key = "YourCache|" + typeof(T).FullName;
            YourCache<T> current = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] as YourCache<T>;
            if (current == null)
            {
                current = new YourCache<T>();
                HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] = current;
            }
            return current;
        }
    }

    public T Get(string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key should not be NULL");

        T value;
        if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;

        return defaultValue;
    }

    public void Set(string key, T value)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        _dictionary[key] = value;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }
}
```

you could call items from cache or even clear them using the following:

```
 // put something in this intermediate cache
YourCache<ClassObject>.Current.Set("myKey", myObj);

// clear this cache
YourCache<ClassObject>.Current.Clear();
```